# R error overwriting file that is not there

Tags: r, file, overwrite, openxlsx

I'm trying to write a file using `openxlsx`:

```
saveWorkbook(wb, file=filename, overwrite=T)
```

gives me no error but no file appears, while

```
> saveWorkbook(wb, file=filename, overwrite=F)
Error in saveWorkbook(wb, file = filename, overwrite = F) : 
  File already exists!
```

I can see t6his quite clearly in R:

```
> filename
[1] "/home/balter/miseq-239/analysis/beta_diversity//tables/miseq-239_beta_diversity_Genus_clust_unifrac_permanova.xlsx"
> filedir = gsub('\\/[^/]+$', '', filename)
> filedir
[1] "/home/balter/miseq-239/analysis/beta_diversity//tables"
> file.exists(filename)
[1] TRUE
> list.files(path=filedir)
character(0)
```

What is going on?

Comment: @IceCreamToucan It comes from using the R function `file.path` that assembles file paths. The double slashes don't matter at all in Linux.

Comment: Just a small note, you can use `dirname(filename)` to get the parent directory path of a file in a more portable way than by using `gsub`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to replicate this issue through simulation.  How sure are you that the file is not created (e.g. can you run `file.exists` immediately after `saveWorkbook`?).  I would update `openxlsx` and see if you can replicate this example in a new session.

```r
library(openxlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook("Creator of workbook")
addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "My first worksheet")

tmp <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")

# Create when file does not exist [overwrite = TRUE]
file.exists(tmp)
#> [1] FALSE
saveWorkbook(wb, file = tmp, overwrite = TRUE)
#> Note: zip::zip() is deprecated, please use zip::zipr() instead
file.exists(tmp)
#> [1] TRUE

# Create when file does not exist [overwrite = FALSE]
file.remove(tmp)
#> [1] TRUE
file.exists(tmp)
#> [1] FALSE
saveWorkbook(wb, file = tmp, overwrite = FALSE)
file.exists(tmp)
#> [1] TRUE

# Create when file exists [overwrite = TRUE]
file.exists(tmp)
#> [1] TRUE
saveWorkbook(wb, file = tmp, overwrite = TRUE)
file.exists(tmp)
#> [1] TRUE

# Create when file exists [overwrite = FALSE]
file.exists(tmp)
#> [1] TRUE
saveWorkbook(wb, file = tmp, overwrite = FALSE)
#> Error in saveWorkbook(wb, file = tmp, overwrite = FALSE): File already exists!
file.exists(tmp)
#> [1] TRUE


sessionInfo()
#> R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/local/Cellar/openblas/0.3.7/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.7.dylib
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] openxlsx_4.1.0.1
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] compiler_3.6.1  magrittr_1.5    tools_3.6.1     htmltools_0.4.0
#>  [5] yaml_2.2.0      Rcpp_1.0.2      stringi_1.4.3   rmarkdown_1.16 
#>  [9] highr_0.8       knitr_1.25      stringr_1.4.0   xfun_0.10      
#> [13] digest_0.6.21   zip_2.0.4       rlang_0.4.0     evaluate_0.14
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I totally understand. I wouldn't expect you to be able to replicate it. In fact, I've never had this problem before. I believe it is some glitch between R and the Linux filesystem such that R sees some phantom file or something. Any idea how such a thing might arise?